# Scrolling issue on chat room when entire message div is replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I want to create a chat room that updates the a div automatically every x milliseconds with new messages that are posted which appear in the `#messagearea` div, being scrolled to the bottom. This is the pseudocode I am using to do this.

```
function fetch_messages{
    loadmsgs();
    $("#messagearea").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 300);
}
```

So every time new messages are loaded, it scrolls down to the bottom.

But this poses a problem. It doesn't allow the user to scroll up as it keeps scrolling to the bottom each time messages are fetched and updated on the page. When the user tries to scroll up, the javascript forces the scrollbar down to the bottom every 1000 milliseconds.

So I want...

- `#messagearea` updates every 1000 milliseconds
- When new messages appear, the `#messagearea` scrolls to the bottom (if the user is already scrolled to the bottom)
- The user is allowed to scroll up even though the web browser keeps scrolling to the bottom each time `#messagearea` is updated

Is updating the entire `#messagearea`, a bad idea, or do I have to `.append` ?

Comment: You could always take into account if the scrollbar is not at the bottom, don't move the scrollbar.

Comment: Instead, like facebook does, at the top of a messenger box, place a small overlay that says new messages are present, or something along those lines

Comment: @OliverQueen I tried to do that, but I couldn't get it to work. https://gist.github.com/desbest/9a8633b54b19fcfaebb93d78714292f2

Comment: Have you tried working with http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp ?

Comment: Can you post how you are appending the message to the div in loadmsgs?

Comment: @SanjeeviRajagopalan https://gist.github.com/desbest/38648c2344509471ba3b9da4fbcadf39#file-process-js

Comment: Two things - (1) Why are you loading all chat messages every time? Can you not only load the new ones and append it to the end of the div? (2) Do you necessarily have to scroll down when you load new messages? Just keep loading the new ones and user will decide himself if he wants to read the first or the last. Moving to end without any apparent event trigger from user just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: (1) I got the code from a tutorial and it had bugs and bad code, so I am fixing it up. I'll append new messages later. (2) Yes I do have to scroll down each time a new message appears when scrolled to the bottom _unless_ the user has scrolled up, otherwise I will have a situation like this, which is bad usability. http://i.imgur.com/2YGav1O.gifv It doesn't show the latest message as it's not scrolled the bottom. I am trying to fix that usability.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea ,I used to avoid such a situation is
>   
>  **"played a sound on new messages "**

its in youtube 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIuyZn5fNs4&feature=youtu.be

> Actually what you are trying to achieve will be very uncomfortable for most users
>   because while reading some messages above , it will automatically scrolls down to bottom on new updates.

**A simple solution will be**

> Add a button on top which enables the users to scroll to bottom on a single click and some mechanism(like play sound) to notify the user on new messages.

I used `append` , just appends the latest **unseen** messages

Comment: Yes, but the user will have to scroll down every time a new message appears, which is bad UX (usability).

Comment: the problem I mentioned is also a bad UX(usability).

Comment: for avoiding both problems , add a button top which enables the users to scroll to bottom on a single click and notify the user on new messages.